# SpringBoot and GitLab CI to run tests

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I would like to just use GitLab CI to run test only not to deploy my app. I manage to assembly this `.yml` file:

```
image: java:8

stages:
  - build
  - test

build:
  stage: build
  script: ./gradlew build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/libs/myApp-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

unitTests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - ./gradlew test
```

And in the GitLab Pipeline I get the following error:

> ar.com.sebasira.myApp.myAppApplicationTests > contextLoads FAILED
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException
>   Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException

I'm guessing this could be related to database, right? I need to provide that database with credentials in my Server where the runner is?

If so, how should I do it? I'currently using `application.properties` file to define the connection to the DB.

And one more question... in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file I need to put the path to the `.jar` but that filename will change everytime I update the version of my app. Do I need to manually change it?

Comment: Use `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` environment variable along with the other properties converted to snake_case and UPPERCASE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are starting the whole Spring context with this test (I think it's the generated standard test from Spring Boot) with the annotations `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` and `@SpringBootTest` you have to provide a datasource. You can do one of the following:

- Specify the database credentials in your `application.properties` in `src/test/resources` (you could provide a test database on your database server as I wouldn't connect to your production database on every test)
- Use an embedded `H2` for this test
- Use https://www.testcontainers.org/ to provide a real and fresh database for your Spring application test

Regarding your GitlabCI question: Just use `*` to match any `.jar` no matter which version: `- build/libs/myApp-*.jar`

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much for your answer! I'll see if I can configure a H2 and also take a look at testcontainers.

Comment: One more question... I double check, I'm not using `@SpringBootTest` just `@WebMvcTest`. For now I don't want to provide a FULL test just a SLICE. The test do not uses database. But I guess that the script tries to launch the app

Comment: The `@WebMvcTest` should only start the MVC slice. Did you delete the default Spring Boot test which comes with the Spring intializer?

Comment: I've just saw the same thing! That's why I return the Accepted Answer. When I read again the error and see the `contextLoads FAILED` I remember about that default auto generated test, remove it and now it works! Thanks again.

Comment: I saw the CI server performs the two task: `build` and `unitTest`. If I just want to run the test, there's no need for the `build` task right? Because I was looking at the job perform and in both cases it builds the app (or at least I think so)

Comment: yes, if you just want to test the application you don't need a build (creating a `.jar`), you just need the compiled sources which is part of the testing

Comment: I remove the `build` job and now GitLab says it's invalid. So I guess is mandatory that build exists and passes in order to run test.

Comment: I would suggest to open a new Stackoverflow question for this and then I can have a look at it. You can put a link to it here